# Jackson/Hibernate, meta get methods and serialization

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson, jackson-databind

We have lot of hibernate entity classes with nested relationships. I'm trying to find best way to convert given entity to equivalent json format.

I know about JsonIgnore, Jackson mixins and JsonFilters and have been experimenting with those.

Challenges we are facing are as following

1. Objects related to each other using OneToMany/JoinColumn or similar annotations - creates infinite recursion.
2. Utility or meta methods. Jackson seems to be going by getter methods and not by fields. Some of the methods are "meta" method that is not associated with any columns. Example getTotal method can be summing of values of couple of actual fields without having actual total field. Similar case for other cases like getIncomeAccounts which filters accounts based on some criteria.

Jackson Filter I wrote helps a little - it checks if the class field exists based on Jackson property name. It also checks if there annotations such as JoinColumn annotation to avoid recursion if the field exists.

Is there any way I can get metadata from hibernate and use it in my filters? Basically for given entity object, I am interested in knowing if the property Jackson wants to serialize will be mapped to a column and serialize only if there is column value associated with it. Hibernate is certainly aware of properties and column mappings.

Mixins and jsonignore options are workable, but then we depend upon individual developer remembering about putting annotations at appropriate place. Usually forgotten annotations are discovered too late when we really want to get the exported data to analyze some problem and create test case locally.

Comment: A workaround would be to create a duplicate class for the sole purpose of serialization that only contains the desired fields, and e.g. copy over everything from the entity to the dto using reflection

Comment: Was below answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is map *Entities* to *DTOs* manually, or with the help of tools such as [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/).
This will give you maximum flexibility, with a bit of overhead at the beginning, unfortunately.
Over time however, you'll see it was worth it.

Jackson, GSON, and other serialization tools are obviously limited in what they can do out-of-the-box, and this kind of customization requires a bit too much work, imho, while also being difficult to understand and maintain.

Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to create new `POJO` model for representing `JSON` on `REST API` level you need to prepare `ORM` model before passing to `Jackson` layer.

### Enable HibernateXModule

You should start from enabling [`Hibernate` module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) which fits the best to your `Hibernate` version. It solves many problem with `lazy-loadings` and internal data types.

### Bidirectional Relationships

[Read about options](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) which `Jackson` have for solving cycles problem during serialisation. Main annotations are:

- [JsonManagedReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html)
- [JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html)
- [JsonIdentityInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html)

### Define proper Visibility

You can define global visibility on `ObjectMapper`, [how to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally) and customise it if needed for given class using [JsonAutoDetect](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect.html) annotation.

### View `POJO` model

Probably for most cases you will be able to reuse `POJO` model created for `ORM`. In cases where customising `JSON` output with annotation will be to hard you can always create custom class and map `ORM` model to this one manually in extra mapping/business layer.

### Customise serialisers

In case you need to handle some custom annotations or some fields in general way you can use [BeanSerializerModifier](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html) and [BeanPropertyWriter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanPropertyWriter.html). It is not easy to implement but it is very powerful. See example usage here: [Jackson custom serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249054/jackson-custom-serialization-and-deserialization).

Simple example how it could be done for bidirectional relations and visibility configuration:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Item item0 = new Item();
        item0.setId(1);
        item0.setItemName("Item 0");

        Item item1 = new Item();
        item1.setId(2);
        item1.setItemName("Item 1");

        List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(item0, item1);
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(123);
        user.setName("Rick");
        user.setUserItems(items);
        items.forEach(item -> item.setOwner(user));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
    }
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Item> userItems;

    // getters, setters
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
class Item {

    private int id;
    private String itemName;
    private User owner;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"id":123,"name":"Rick","userItems":[{"id":1,"itemName":"Item 0","owner":123},{"id":2,"itemName":"Item 1","owner":123}]}
```