# Jackson: How to prevent recursive call by only adding ID field inside child collections

Tags: recursion, serialization, jackson, entity-relationship, bidirectional

I wanted to simplify my question. I have a parent and a child entity.

```
public class Parent {
  private String name;
  @OneToMany
  private List<Child> childs;
}
```

and

```
public class Child {
  private String name;
  @ManyToOne
  private Parent parent;
}
```

What I want to do is when I serialize these entities, it should like this.

```
{
  "parentList": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "parent",
      "childs": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "chiled",
          "parent" : "1"
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "childList": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "child",
      "parent": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "parent",
          "childs": [
            {
              "id": "1",
            }
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Like this:

```
Parent -> Child -> parentID
Child -> Parent -> childID
```

If I update my entities like as you can see below.

```
public class Parent {
  private String name;
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  @OneToMany
  private List<Child> childs;
}
```

and

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Child {
  private String name;
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  @ManyToOne
  private Parent parent;
}
```

With this setup I get **almost** what I want.

```
Child -> Parent -> ChildID (good)
Parent -> ChildID (bad)
```

I need Parent to have whole Child entity and that Child entity should only have parentID. If I add `@JsonIdentityInfo` to both entities, then result looks like this:

```
Child -> parentID (bad)
Parent -> childID (bad)
```

If I remove `@JsonIdentityInfo` from both, then I have recursive problem again.

Don't know how to get what I want.

Comment: You can start from [Jackson/Hibernate, meta get methods and serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383889/jackson-hibernate-meta-get-methods-and-serialization/55386877#55386877) question. Take a look at `JsonManagedReference`, `JsonBackReference` and `JsonIdentityInfo` annotations. See also: [Jackson - serialization of entities with birectional relationships (avoiding cycles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065002/jackson-serialization-of-entities-with-birectional-relationships-avoiding-cyc)

Comment: @MichałZiober I simplified my question, so I hope it is less confusing now :)

Comment: following......

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "**JsonIgnore**" annotation to prevent the unwanted data comes from the parant entity into the child.

```
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public class Child {
      private String name;
      @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
      @ManyToOne
      @JsonIgnore      <- HERE
      private Parent parent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior. Normally you wouldn't want to do what you are proposing, so Jackson ships by default with that in mind.

## One possibility:

However, since Jackson is nothing more than a java library, you can extend and modify it to suit your needs. My first suggestion would be to create different [`Scopes`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html#scope()) for the `parent -> child -> parents` and for the `child -> parent -> child`.

## Why it's probably a bad idea:

Regardless of that, it's important to understand why this isn't a default behavior:

If you have `Child` and `Parent` in a relationship where a `Child` can only have one `Parent` and `Parent`s can have multiple `Child`s, then:

```
  A         B            C
Child -> Parent -> List<ChildID>
```

- A and B are different.
- A is contained in C.
- C can also contain other `Child`.

but,

```
  A         B                   C (missing)
Parent -> List<ChildID> ----> Parent
```

- B contains multiple `Child`
- Each missing C would be equal to A.

So, if your problem only appears when you approach `Parent` to get `List<Child>`, then you already have your solution. Since the `Parent` of each and every `Child` in the list would be the parent that has the list in the first place.

Therefore, you don't need the C that is missing, since it's already the element A.

Hope this helps!