# What is wrong if DAO deals with @JsonInclude annotated objects?

Tags: java, oop, architecture, jackson, dao

In my team lot of fights I see as some people using `@JsonInclude` annotated objects in `DAO` layer and some people argues to not to use and I could not able to find the reason for this.

Please anyone suggests.

Comment: Talk to your team.

Comment: What is your take on that? What is your analysis

Comment: Please anyone can answer.

Comment: Annotations in general break the principle of loose coupling. The question is should you make your DAOs dependent on the JSON package. The other thing is I am not entirely sure you have DAOs in mind. Do you mean POJOs?

Answer (score 1):

Are the @Json annotations on DTO objects that you use to define your DAO interfaces? It might indicate that you reuse the same objects to define an external API like REST.

A consideration might be that if you reuse these objects, that you will couple the REST API to the DAO API. You need to consider if this is acceptable for you.

For applications that you have completely under control, it might be acceptable.

If you have clients that need a stable version of the REST API, you might want to use different DTO objects for your REST API (with @Json annotations) and for your DAO, so you can change your DAO's interfaces without having to change your REST API. But you need to maintain double classes and have extra mapping code to map between them.

Answer (score 1):

`Jackson` does not force developer to link domain model with it's annotations. In most cases you can use [MixIn](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-mixin-annotations) feature and add annotation to given class, methods, properties in Runtime.

There is no "right" approach you can use in every project. Generally, it depends from: team, business requirements, used frameworks, etc.

If you want to show in `REST API` model as it is used for `DB` you can use `Jackson` annotations directly on given class as you probably do with `Hibernate` annotations. But in case you just want to show some part of a model in `REST API` you can create a separate model and use some mapping tools ([Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/), [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/), [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/)) or use `MixIn` feature, I mentioned about before, and reuse `ORM` model.

Definitely, you should use in a project **one** approach. Every class is annotated with `Jackson` or none of them. Using it partially makes a mess and it is hard to maintain project like this.

To make decision easier, you can read:

- [Domain Driven Design by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/tags/domain%20driven%20design.html)
- [Domain Driven Design and Development In Practice](https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice/)
- [Jackson/Hibernate, meta get methods and serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383889/jackson-hibernate-meta-get-methods-and-serialization)