# How to avoid Jackson getting fields marked as FetchType.LAZY?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

In Country class I have:

```
@OneToMany(
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
```

And despite it's marked as LAZY (I guess) Jackson makes that when a request is made, it gets each country along wih its list of cities. Is there any annotation to handle this?

Comment: Are you using `@Data` from Lombok?

Comment: yes, could it be messing something up?

Comment: Yes, it has `@EqualsAndHashCode` internally it will call `cities` for object matching

Comment: One more question I have, When you call for the country do you need a list of cities in the response?

Comment: I just tried removing @Data and it remains the same. And that's my problem. When I call for countries I shouldn't get  their cities as well. That's why I set cities up as LAZY but because of Jackson it's not working.

Comment: You can use `@JsonIgnore` on cities

Comment: Try to register [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) and take a look on this question [Jackson/Hibernate, meta get methods and serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383889/jackson-hibernate-meta-get-methods-and-serialization)